# Unicode strings syntax in Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

[Official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) states that Unicode strings in Python can be used like this:

```
u'Hello World !'
```

But when I put it to IDLE - Python GUI of Python 3.2, it gives me a syntax error. Also Russian and Chinese text can be succcessfully stored in that Python strings, so I guess they are already Unicode.

Could you please explain what's happening?

Comment: You should use the official Python 3.2 tutorial, since you are using Python 3.2: http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by default python 3.2 works with unicode strings so the `u` is no longer needed.

If you want to encode and decode strings you should use:

```
encoded = "unicodestring".encode("UTF8")

decoded = s.decode("UTF8")
```

The [Python documetation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) states that:

> Python 3.0 uses the concepts of text and (binary) data instead of Unicode strings and 8-bit strings. All text is Unicode; however encoded Unicode is represented as binary data. The type used to hold text is str

and

> You can no longer use u"..." literals for Unicode text. However, you must use b"..." literals for binary data.

Answer (score 3):

In Python3.3+ unicode literal is valid again, see [What’s New In Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#summary-release-highlights):

> New syntax features:
>
> New yield from expression for generator delegation.
>   **The u'unicode' syntax is accepted again for str objects.**